# In LTspice XVII, 74HC107 has an error, but I can't figure out what the problem is

Tags: ltspice, flipflop

[image]

I made a circuit like this picture above with LTspice XVII.

Q(0), Q(1), Q(2) are output, and CL is CLK (clock pulse).

JKFFs are negative-edge-triggered JK flip-flop (ie. 74HC107).

[image]

And, the graph of this circuit should look like this picture below:

[image]

But, LTspice shows a graph like this:

[image]

(Sorry, I made every effort to be clearer but I can't make it.)

I can't understand that Q(0) turns out 5V at 0μs ~ 20μs. I mean, negative edge-triggered JK flip-flop works when CLK changes from 5V to 0V. So, shouldn't Q(0) be 0V at 0μs ~ 20μs? By the way, why does Q(0) in LTspice turn out 5V at 0μs ~ 20μs?

Did I make a mistake when I set the circuit up?

**More details**

[image]

Component attribute of 74HC107:

[image]

Component attribute of 74HC08:

74HC08 = 2-input, 1-output And Gate

[image]

Information about CLK(V2):

[image]

Information about Edit Simulation Command

Comment: @user299980 I don't have, and haven't studied, the 74HC library you are using. Do you have documentation on it? It's possible that the answer is to be found there.

Comment: @jonk You mean I should send 74HC.lib to you? Yes, I have documentation. But, how could I send it to you, sir?

Comment: @user299980 I'm merely pointing out (1) that I have no way to help out and (2) that you may be able to find what you need by reading the documentation. You appear to be asking "why does it do X when I think it should do Y, instead?" (Rising vs falling edge.) Obviously, without the library in hand, no experience with it, and no documentation to it I'm probably not going to be a lot of help. You've done an excellent job documenting your voltage sources. So I am already convinced that you've reviewed your own work so far as that goes. I doubt I'll find a mistake there that you haven't found.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for your detailed explanation. My English is very poor, so I misread.

Comment: @user299980 My German is poor (I can read it, but I am really bad producing it.) I only have the utmost respect for your English skills!

Comment: @jonk You're so kind and good-natured person. Thank you. Thanks to you, I could gain confidence in English. I respect you and your kindly heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTspice is an analog simulator. Before running the .tran analysis of your circuit, the simulator calculates the initial state of the circuit, the voltages and currents at t=0, using the 74HC107 model which it takes from the 74hc.lib library. If you know the simulator algorithms and the library internals and can manage with this knowledge to your avail, it is possible to predict what the initial state the simulator arrive at after completing the initial stage of your .tran run.

But you know this result from your attempt, and it is not what you expect it should be: you'd like to start from Q[0] = 0, Q[1] = 0, Q[2] = 0; however, the simulator starts from Q[0] = 1, Q[1] = 0, Q[2] = 0. In principle, you can shift slightly the timing in the beginning and separate the power on and the CLK pulse train start with the purpose of arriving at the "correct" initial state, but you should not. Remember, the purpose of simulating the circuit is to examine the behavior of a real hardware design, and the practical implementation of a digital counter embraces the initial setting of the counter into a required state. In your case, you want it to be Q[0] = 0, Q[1] = 0, Q[2] = 0. The 74HC107 device has an input for re-setting the device, named an asynchronous reset input, which is active LOW. 74HC107 is a dual JK flip flop, and it has two pins, 13 and 10, one input for each of its two flip flops.  In datasheets, these inputs are designated \$1 \overline R\$ and \$2 \overline R\$.

In your circuit these inputs are named CLRs, and you connected these pins to a constant 5V. You should add to your circuit the reset signal connected to these CLR inputs and start the simulation run with these inputs at LOW (OV). After a delay that guarantees that flip flops are set to Q[0] = 1, Q[1] = 0, Q[2] = 0, you set the CLR inputs to HIGH (5V). For the entire interval of this initial delay, the CLK signals connected to CLK inputs should be disabled (gated with this common CLR signal). With this initial setting, you will have the expected timing diagram, starting from [0, 0, 0], and not from [5V, 0, 0], as is the case with your circuit.

Comment: I'm very much obliged to you. I extended End Time from 200us to 220us. And, I prolonged reset signal with 0V at 0~20us. And thanks to you, I was able to have the expected timing diagram at 20~220us. You really made my day! As soon as I exceed 15 rep, I'll cast a vote "This answer is useful". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you compare the graph in your 3rd picture (let's call it P3) with the LTspice simulation and count the number of clock pulses until all the outputs go low, you'll see that in P3 you have 5 cycles, while in LTspice you only have 4. This means that in P3 there (probably) is a reset signal that is low right at the beginning and for a short while, then goes high, all during the duration of the 1st clock cycle. If there isn't such a thing, then whatever generated P3 must have considered that the whole counter is reset during the 1st cycle.

Therefore you need such a signal in your schematic: add a voltage source with `PWL(5u 5 6u 0)` (a ***P****iece****w****ise* ***L****inear* function that at 5 μs has 5 V, between 5 and 6 μs it drops linearly to 0 V, then stays that way). Delete `V3`, `V4`, and `V5` (you only needed one, anyway, and it could have even been `V1`), then connect all the `CLR` pins to this source. BTW, you don't need tyo exaggerate the rising/falling times like that: it's enough to make them about 100x...1000x lower than the period (so for a `20u` period make then `20n`).

Comment: I'm very much obliged to you. I extended End Time from 200us to 220us. And, I prolonged reset signal with 0V at 0~20us. And I was able to have the expected timing diagram at 20~220us. And, I tweaked rising/falling times as you said. I really really would like to reiterate how grateful am I. Thank you, my hero! As soon as I exceed 15 rep, I'll cast a vote "This answer is useful". Thank you very much!